# ReactJs - Compiled with warning

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
    Warning
    (6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

    WARNING in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
    Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
```

I encounter this warning while running react-bootstrap(v2.3.1 (Bootstrap 5.1)) with reactjs(v18.1.0). How to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you read the message and try to do what it says? You are using `color-adjust` in your CSS, and you should use `print-color-adjust`.

Comment: Please read error messages before asking questions, and if you don't understand them, please search for the error message first https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259

Comment: I tried it, Doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide more information on your set up. How did you bootstrap your project? What version of react and react-bootstrap are you using? Is it a fresh and clean project or did you already coded something? etc. etc.

Comment: Azizur Rahman - please write what did you try to do. In that Github issue @andy-ray mentioned they write how to fix it, at least temporarily, before the fix in Bootstrap comes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 9):

You can add it into package.json

- First Step

  ```
  "resolutions": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  },
  ```
- Second Step

> yarn install

** If you are using npm

- First Step

  ```
  "overrides": {
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
  },
  ```
- Second Step

> npm install

** Summarize from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259#issuecomment-1114855186

Comment: AFAIU this just hides the problem rather than fixing it. See my other answer for a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72299465/473672

Answer (score 1):

Bump bootstrap to 5.2.0 or newer.

Bootstrap 5.1.3 still has this problem.

As I'm typing this, the latest bootstrap 5.2.0 version is `5.2.0-beta1`, which given its beta status may or may not be something you want to upgrade to, but [upgrading to that will at least solve *this* problem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259#issuecomment-1128222959).

The root cause here is that bootstrap generates CSS with deprecated tags. Notice how your error message implicates bootstrap:

```
    WARNING in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem still exists for me even upgrading to bootstrap 5.2.0-beta1 and upon inspection of the installed bootstrap it appears to be using latest autoprefixer. I see no solution currently. If there is a way to create a js/tsx file to override that would be nice.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31976638)

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting overrides didn't work for me. I had do go through the following steps :

Add this to package.json:

```
"overrides": { "autoprefixer": "10.4.5" }
```

Delete `package-lock.json`

Delete the `node_modules/` directory

Run `npm install` to install the npm modules back

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css, in my case is bootstrap.min.css
2. ctrl+F or find text -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;color-adjust:exact
3. change the color-adjust to print-color-adjust
4. problem solved